# ct: not yet implemented

Tags: linux, shell, clearcase

In Linux when I try to run `ct setview` inside shell script I am getting `ct: not yet implemented` error but if I run same command in command line I am able to run the command.

Can anyone please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow some tutorials like [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ClearcaseCommands.html) it appears that `ct` is an alias for `/usr/atria/bin/cleartool` and not a command.

Aliases are only available in interactive shells, not in shell scripts.

Use:

```
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool
```

instead of

```
ct
```

in your script.

Comment: thank you but after running setview command I am not able do cd command can you please help me in this

Comment: I've never tried clear case before, I can't help with that.